# Find the areas of the rectangle ABCD. Given E is midpoint of side AD.

Tags: geometry

[image]

Main problem for me is to find the radius of the circle. Given I was able to get the area in terms of radius using Pythagoras theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote the center of the circle by $O$ and the radius by $r$. The angle $\angle AOE = 30^\circ$ because $\sin 30^\circ = 1/2$. We have

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}=\tan 30^\circ = \frac{AE}{OA} = \frac{r/2}{OA}.
$$

The area of rectangle $ABCD$ is going to be:

$$
\text{Area} = (OA+OB)BC = (\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}r+r)r=(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} + 1)r^2.
$$

Now the angle $\angle EOB = 150^\circ$. By the Law of Cosines,

$$
10^2=r^2+r^2-2r^2\cos150^\circ = 2r^2(1-\cos150^\circ).
$$

Consequently

$$
\text{Area} = (\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} + 1)r^2=(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} + 1)\frac{10^2}{2(1-\cos 150^\circ)} = 50.
$$